# webgrind on wamp

Tags: php, profiling, wamp, xdebug

I just installed wamp and the latest version comes with webgrind, but i cannot figure out how it works.It says

```
Select a cachegrind file above
```

And thats all.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Webgrind is a parser/viewer for a profiling file format called cachegrind. The PHP extension [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org) can (among other very useful things) generate these. For webgrind to work, Xdebug needs to be installed and enabled.

1. Make sure Xdebug is installed and working (see the [Xdebug docs](http://xdebug.org/docs/) for info on how to do that)
2. Have Xdebug generate a profiling report by requesting a local PHP file
3. Load webgrind in the browser and select a file in the popup-menu at the top
4. Press `update`, and hopefully everything should work

The [wiki on Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/webgrind/wiki/Installation) has more on configuring webgrind.

Comment: To me, the last step wasn't producing anything (there was no change on screen), but webgrind was actually making the update call. After checking, it turned out that local webserver was spitting out a bunch of PHP notices (webgrind's issues), which were breaking the page-behavior.  I added a `php_flag error_reporting E_NONE` into the .htaccess file, in the webgrind folder and it all worked!

Answer (score 14):

1) Download XDebug from their [download page](http://xdebug.org/download.php).

2) Put all DLL files in your PHP extension directory: `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.x.x\ext`

3) Add the following line in your `php.ini` file located in `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.x.x`:

```
zend_extension = c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0\ext\php_xdebug-2.1.0-5.3-vc6.dll
```

4) Add also the following section to your php.ini (search for the [xdebug] section first to make sure it does not exist yet):

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "c:\wamp\www\webgrind\tmp"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
```

5) Restart Wamp and verify that the extension was loaded.  To do so, add a file `pi.php` in `C:\wamp\www\` and put the following code in it:

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

6) Check the output by opening your browser at `http://localhost/pi.php` and search for XDebug.

7) Download Webgrind from their [download page](https://code.google.com/p/webgrind/downloads/list) and extract in in your `www` folder.

8) Edit the `config.php`file located in `C:\wamp\www\webgrind\` to change the storage directories:

```
static $storageDir = 'c:\wamp\www\webgrind\tmp';
static $profilerDir = 'c:\wamp\www\webgrind\tmp';
```

9) In the Webgrind directory where you have extracted the code, add an `.htaccess` file and put this content in it to avoid webgrind from profiling itself:

```
php_flag xdebug.profiler_enable 0
```

10) Rerun the `http://localhost/pi.php` script to generate some profiling data.

11) Open your browser with `http://localhost/webgrind` to display the results. Do not forget to click the `Update` button!

This answer is based on an answer provided by Jacob Moen. You can view the original source [here](https://jacmoe.dk/blog/2010/november/how-to-install-xdebug-and-webgrind-on-wamp).

Comment: And what happens if that blog goes away or that post gets moved? Link-only questions have a limited life-span on the Internet; better to list the relevant points here like jokkedk did (or post a link as a comment instead of an “answer”).

Comment: Hope you'll appreciate the effort! ;-)

Comment: Personally, sort of. I don’t currently use Xdebug or webgrind, so it means little to me (though I am looking into it at the moment), but others will definitely appreciate it, especially in the future when people come across your post—or cached/ripped copies of it—via a search engine, and the blog you linked to is no longer available. Either way, [link-only answers are really frowned upon](http://www.google.com/search?q=link+only+answers) for the reasons I just explained, so by improving your answer, it won’t get deleted or converted to a comment and in fact will get up-voted. `;-)`

Comment: Make sure to specif the directory where the xdebug module is located. That can be a [stumbling point](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20111302/119540).

Answer (score 0):

> It is good to watch if the application becomes SLOW, had problems with
>   it because of the settings of Cachegrind.
>
> Good luck!
>
> My settings are Wamp 2.4, Apache 2.4, PHP 5.4 and MySQL 5.6

[Portugues pt_BR]

É bom prestar atenção se a aplicação se tornar LENTA, tive problemas com isso por causa das configurações do cachegrind.

Boa sorte!

Minhas configurações são Wamp 2.4, Apache 2.4, PHP 5.4 e MySQL 5.6

Answer (score 0):

Update the PHP.INI with these parameters

- xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
- xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 1

RESTART ALL SERVICES

this should be work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do much....

I just edited the line to be

`xdebug.profiler_enable = 1`

Thats all buddy. Totally works!