# What does "XDEBUG NOT LOADED AS ZEND EXTENSION" warning means?

Tags: php, xdebug

Xdebug is loaded, but not loaded as a zend extension. What does it mean? How to resolve this problem?

Comment: What's your configuration? What's inside your **php.ini**? (`zend_extension_debug=*`). More details would be appreciate.

Comment: How do you know it's not loaded as zend extension? Where did you read that? Can you provide a screenshot?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This error means that you used "extension=" to load Xdebug. That could be in your normal php.ini, or in a file called xdebug.ini that some distributions like to add. In any case, Xdebug needs to be loaded as a Zend extension for certain features such as single step debugging. As Xdebug is not meant to work as a normal extension, it might crash and burn too.

The syntax for loading Xdebug as Zend extension depends on PHP version and build. I would suggest you use http://xdebug.org/wizard.php to provide you with the correct lines.

Comment: "In any case, Xdebug needs to be loaded as a Zend extension" – can you explain why? When I install xdebug via PECL I'm told to add "extension=xdebug.so" to my php.ini and a phpinfo() reports all kinds of goodness about how xdebug is installed and working, but it also reminds me that it's "not loaded as a Zend extension" without any explanation of why I would care.

Comment: At least in Windows, xdebug wizard makes a small mistake: it suggests adding something like `zend_extension = C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.1-5.3-vc9-nts.dll`. It should be `zend_extension = "C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.1-5.3-vc9-nts.dll"` to actually work.

Comment: @texnic Thanks!. The wizard stated to add "zend_extension = ext\" to the php.ini. It should have said to add the xdebug.dll as part of the extension path, for example: "zend_extension = ext\php_xdebug-2.2.2.dll". I wasted 30 minutes trying to figure that out.

Comment: This was driving me crazy, xdebug now works, thanks a bunch :)

Comment: @CharlieS, I've clarified that in my answer. I also think that PECL is now finally fixed, but I am not sure whether that is released already.

Answer (score 5):

Others have already explained that the error is because Xdebug is being loaded as a regular PHP module instead of as a Zend extension. You can use the [wizard](http://xdebug.org/wizard.php) that Derick linked to or manually enter the line as Starx showed.

However, there is an issue that you may run into. The `extensions_dir` directive in `php.ini` currently only applies to PHP modules, [not to Zend extensions](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=54564). Therefore, you cannot use a common configuration like this:

```
[PHP]
extension_dir  = .\ext
extension      = php_memcache.dll
…
[zend]
zend_extension = php_xdebug-2.2.3-5.3-vc9-nts.dll
```

While PHP will correctly load `php_memcache.dll` from the `ext` sub-directory, it will *not* load `php_xdebug-2.2.3-5.3-vc9-nts.dll` and will throw the error `Failed loading php_xdebug-2.2.3-5.3-vc9-nts.dll`.

To fix this, you will need to either use an fully-qualified/absolute path such as:

```
zend_extension = C:\foobar\PHP\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.3-5.3-vc9-nts.dll
```

or a relative path such as these:

```
zend_extension = ext\php_xdebug-2.2.3-5.3-vc9-nts.dll
zend_extension = ..\phpexts\php_xdebug-2.2.3-5.3-vc9-nts.dll
zend_extension = \dev\phpexts\php_xdebug-2.2.3-5.3-vc9-nts.dll
```

(The wizard will return `zend_extension=.\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.3-5.3-vc9-nts.dll` which includes the directory but also a superfluous `.\`)

Answer (score 4):

Make sure if it is configured to load correctly as a `zend_extension`. Inside `php.ini` add this line

```
zend_extension="/usr/local/php/modules/xdebug.so"
```

Comment: In my CentOS 6 installation, it is: `zend_extension=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/xdebug.so` (Also, I have a local php.ini in my web root that over rides the default php.ini. It seems I have to add the directive there if I want it to work inside of that web path.)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to activate `zend*nts*.dll` into you `php.ini` file on Windows servers, you must use `zend_extension_ts` directive instead of `zend_extension` 
**Example to load xdebug :**

```
[XDeug]
zend_extension_ts="DRIVE:/PATH_TO_XDEBUG/php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.show_local_vars=1
xdebug.default_enable=On
```

Note : the double quotes to your dll file

Hope that will helps someone :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all In **PHP 5.3** and later, you need to use only `zend_extension`, **not** `zend_extension_ts`, `zend_extension_debug`, or `extension`.

The php.ini file should look like this

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-3.2.0RC2-8.1-vs16-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1
```

**Attention!!** to avoid errors you need to install the correct xdebug library file.

For example, assuming you using windows and install this `xamp` version `xampp-windows-x64-8.1.10-0-VS16-installer`. The valid **.dll** xdebug file would be `PHP 8.1 VS16 TS (64 bit)` to download.

Do all the above and i guarantee no loading errors or problems

Answer (score 0):

If you end up here while trying to *build* xdebug, then it means you have built it as a "static" extension (not a zend one).

You can use `configure --with-xdebug=shared` to build it as a shared extension (dll/so; you should see a table showing that xdebug is now configured to be built as a shared extension instead of a static one) so it can be loaded as a zend extension afterward.

I don't know if you can make a static zend extension.

Also, note that running the full test suite of xdebug requires to not activate opcache (`configure --disable-opcache --with-xdebug=shared`)

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me: in php.ini

```
zend_extension = php_xdebug-3.0.4-8.0-vs16-x86_64.dll
```