# How to stop Xdebug to stop debugging itself?

Tags: php, xdebug, xdebug-profiler, webgrind

I'm using Xdebug with Webgrind.
If I use below settings in php.ini, eveything works fine:

```
zend_extension = /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = /var/www/html/xdebug
```

If I open webgrind by going to **www.example.com/webgrind**, cache.out files are shown and I can analyze  everything fine.

If I use these settings where xdebug will be enabled for every url, cache.out files get generated but when I click on update in webgrind, it just keeps on loading. In my knowledge xdebug starts debugging process on this url as well because xdebug is enabled overall the site.

```
zend_extension = /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = /var/www/html/xdebug
```

How can I disable xdebug process when working inside the /webgrind directory but keep it enabled everywhere else?

I found this post where the second answer clearly mentions the same thing.
[webgrind on wamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808047/webgrind-on-wamp][1])

> In the Webgrind directory where you have extracted the code, add an
>   .htaccess file and put this content in it to avoid webgrind from
>   profiling itself:
>
> `php_flag xdebug.profiler_enable 0`

I've a **nginx+php-fpm** setup, I've converted many .htaccess rules to nginx rewrite rules but not able to do the same with this.

How can I achieve the same with my setup or is there any other way I can get it working? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.user.ini` files that you can use as [equivalence](https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php) to `.htaccess` files. The `.user.ini` file should just contain the following:

```
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
```

Comment: Where should I keep it? What should be the path of the file? From what I read, I should keep it in /var/www/html/webgrind directory, right?

Comment: Yes, in that directory.

Comment: Thanks a lot Derick. It is working fine now. Learnt something new today that I can use .user.ini files for per directory php settings.